# Read input with startup script Finnix 110

Tags: scripting, startup, input

I am in the process of setting up a liveUSB that will run some scripts on a machine when it is booted. The main OS on the USB is finnix 110, and I am setting up startup scripts in the `/indep/rc` directory. So far, this has worked for the most part, but anytime that I want to get user input, the script just skips over the section where it is supposed to wait for input:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo -n "[Select] /dev/:"
read sda
clear
echo /dev/$sda selected
```

On startup, the `read` command doesn't wait for user input, and just continues with `sda` as a blank variable, rather than giving the user a typing prompt.

When I run `./cdrom/finnix/arch/indep/rc/test.sh` the script runs fine and waits for the user's input. I'm not completely sure why it just skips this section when run as a startup script.

Is there any way that I can make this script run *after* startup is completed, like I do manually with the `./path/to/test.sh` command? Or even, is there an alternate way that I can collect user input when it is run in the `/rc/` directory at startup? I've been working on this issue for a couple days using various articles, but none of which have been able to get this working properly.

Comment: it sounds like this script may be running before there's anyone logged in (no getty/terminal started yet). You may want to focus on getting the script to run afterwards.

Comment: @JeffSchaller I mentioned that as a potential solution towards the bottom of my question. The thing is, I'm not sure of the best approach to do what you're saying

Comment: I think you should put it in .profile